# How to implement the list filter function in F# using primitives

Tags: f#, functional-programming, pointfree

I was reading [Why functional programming matters](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf) where the author implements a couple of applications using foldr and function composition. I did the some of them in F# e.g. the map function:

```
let cons a lst = a::lst
let map f lst = List.foldBack (f>>cons) lst []
```

Then I wanted to implement the list filter function and got stuck:

```
let filter pred lst = List.foldBack (what-goes-here?) lst []
```

The *what-goes-here?* function should take as input a list item, the accumulating filtered list and return the same list if the predicate returns false and a cons:ed list if it returns true.

I guess I need the option type here but can't figure out how to glue things together.
Is it possible to compose a function using pred and cons (and perhaps some other primitives) to achieve this **without** writing a custom lambda function which does all the plumbing? Is this a case for computation expressions?

Comment: What's the point of not writing a lambda? Pointless, pardon, point-free style? This obviously works for pure code: `fun x xs -> if f x then x :: xs else xs`. Note that it differs from `List.filter` in presence of side-effects though, `List.foldBack` is not appropriate then.

Comment: Thanks. The point is just me wanting to learn more about fp in general and in this case function composition. Why does it differ from `List.filter` in presence of side-effects?

Comment: @Christian: Because you are reverse traversing the list (`foldBack`) so your side effects will happen in reverse order. (For instance, printing the list)

Comment: You can also peek in the F# source if you ever get stuck. I often dip into to the code for a peek.

Comment: @7sharp9 Yeah I did look up the implementation (`let filter f x = Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.filter f x`) though I didn't find the Basics module.

Comment: @Christian - It is very hidden - https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs at line 163

Comment: This can't be implemented with a simple function composition, and here's the reason: the list element has to be used twice: first as an argument for `pred`, and then as an argument for `cons`. A simple function composition is *monadic*, e.g. once consumed (with `pred`), the element `x` is no longer accessible for further operation. So `what-goes-here` has to have formal argument binding and use `x` twice.

Comment: @bytebuster, perhaps the property you are describing is *linear* (as in *linear logic*), not *monadic*. Regardless, your statement is not correct.  Given a suitable basis, such as the SKI basis, it is possible to express this function without lambda binders.

Comment: @toyvo Correct, `SKI` is untyped lambda calculus and therefore there are no monads there. `S` maps its third argument twice.

Comment: Hmm I wonder why the question got downvoted? The reason for downvoting should be No research effort, unclear or not useful. I would love to know the downvoter's reason so that I can improve this and future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pragmatic answer to your question is:

```
whatGoesHere = fun x xs -> if f x then x :: xs else xs
```

Anonymous functions, if-then-else and lists are all considered
primitives by F# practitioners.  This is the clearest, most
maintainable way to write this code.

Alas, you have not accepted the equivalent correct answer from the
previous responder, and you insist on seeing code involving no
lambda expressions.  You are welcome:

```
``s``s`ks``s`k`s`ks``s``s`ks``s`k`s`ks``s`k`s`kk``s
`k`s`k``s``s`ks``s`k`s`ks``s`k`s`kk``s``s`ks``s`kki
`ki`k`ki``s``s`ks``s`kki`ki
`k``s``s`ks``s`kk``s`k``s``s`ks``s`kk``s`ks``s`k`s`ks
``s`k`s`kk``s`k`si``s`kki`k``s``s`ks
``s`k`s`ks``s`k`s`kk``s``s`ks``s`kki`ki
`k`kii`ki`k`ki
```

The above is `whatGoesHere` in SKI combinator calculus using a suitable
representation of booleans and lists, printed in Unlambda notation.

For your convenience, here is a sample compiler from untyped
lambda calculus to SKI combinators, and the F# definitions of lambda
calculus terms corresponding to your problem:

http://gist.github.com/3277850

While the equivalence of combinatory logic and lambda calculus
makes lambda expressions unnecessary in theory, they are indispensable
for expressing your intent as a programmer.  "Why functional programming matters"
in no way advocates avoiding lambda expressions and helper functions.
To the contrary - the ability to define functions, including
higher-order functions, is at the very core of functional programming. 
It hardly matters whether the functions are defined by composition or
explicitly use lambda calculus: both are the "glue"
the paper talks about.

I suggest you give the paper (and perhaps its excellent references)
another read, and then install Haskell or Clean. Given that the authors
advocate pure lazy-by-default evaluation model, F# is not a good
platform to explore these ideas.

Comment: Thank you, my mind is broadened! :) For the record: I'm not trying to bash lambdas or conditionals, I was just curious whether it was possible, in line with the gluing-examples in "Why functional programming matters", to do the same with the filter-function. In a real-world situation I would certainly chose the most pragmatic and maintainable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
let consT pred a lst = if pred a then a::lst else lst
let filter pred lst = List.foldBack (consT pred) lst []
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I asked for. I was looking for a solution where only primitive composed functions are used and not a custom written function.

Comment: primitive functions such as `(consT pred)` is not.